# Html page scrollable body

Tags: html, scroll

I'm creating a html page with an image as background for the body. I want the image to fit the screen width, so, I set the viewport to screen width. The image is well rendered over the different devices, but when the screen height is very low with respect to the screen width I can't scroll the page vertically, so my image is cut.

Here's my html and css:

```
body{
background:url(images/back.png);
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:#081A28;
}

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=0.1,maximum- scale=10.0,user-scalable=yes"/>
<script src="lib/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

How can I make the body scrollable? I tried with overflow:scroll, but this way a scrollbar appears on the right, but does not give the ability to scroll the page.

Comment: can you make a JSFiddle ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales http://jsfiddle.net/zPSnL/

Comment: What's wrong with http://jsfiddle.net/zPSnL/1/ ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales if the content of the page has a height less than the screen size, but the background image is bigger, the body does not scroll and the background image is cut.